# issue with angularjs ng-pattern special character & (ampersand)

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ng-pattern

issue with angularjs ng-pattern special character & (ampersand)

angularjs ng-pattern="/^[-& A-Za-z'0-9#/]*$/".  Input text filed should be able to take the special character &, but it is not.  Input filed is being reported as invalid.  Any reason why ng-pattern is not allowing & in angularjs.

Comment: just use ^[-& A-Za-z'0-9#/]*$

Comment: Your regex worked for me once I escape the forward slash after the hash.

Comment: How did you escape it, single backward slash, "/^[-& A-Za-z'0-9#\/]*$/" ?  That didn't work me either.